# C# Fluent Interface With Queue or List

Tags: c#, queue, covariance, fluent-interface

I have the following :

```
public interface IBehaviour
{
    event EventHandler Completed;
    void Execute();
}

public interface IBehaviourA : IBehaviour
{
    // Some specific stuff here
    object A { get; set; }
}

public interface IBehaviourB : IBehaviour
{
    // Some specific stuff here
    object B {get;set;}
}

public interface IBehaviourQueue
{
    void Run();
    BehaviourQueueItem<IBehaviour> AddBehaviour<T>() where T : IBehaviour;
}

public class BehaviourQueue : Queue<BehaviourQueueItem<IBehaviour>>,  IBehaviourQueue
{
    private IBehaviourFactory factory;

    public BehaviourQueue(IBehaviourFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public BehaviourQueueItem<IBehaviour> AddBehaviour<T>() where T:IBehaviour
    {
        T behaviour = factory.GetNew<T>();
        var queueItem = new BehaviourQueueItem<IBehaviour>(behaviour);
        Enqueue(queueItem); 
        return queueItem;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        //Run each queue item
    }

}

public class BehaviourQueueItem<T>
{
    public IBehaviour behaviour;
    public BehaviourQueueItem(IBehaviour behaviour)
    {
        this.behaviour = behaviour;
    }
    public void WhenComplete(Func<T, bool> action) 
    {
        CompletedAction = action;
    }

    public BehaviourQueueItem<T> ConfigureFor<Z>(Action<Z> dow) where Z : IBehaviour
    {
        dow((Z)behaviour);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Here is what I can write :

```
        var q =new BehaviourQueue(new BehaviourFactory());
        q
             .AddBehaviour<IBehaviourA>()
             .ConfigureFor<IBehaviourA>(x => x.A = "someValueA")
             .WhenComplete(x => DoStuffWithSomeProperty(((IBehaviourA)x).A));
        q
             .AddBehaviour<IBehaviourB >()
             .ConfigureFor<IBehaviourB >(x => x.B = "someValueB")
             .WhenComplete(x => DoStuffWithSomeProperty(((IBehaviourB)x).B));
```

What I don't really like is that I have to specify which type of IBehaviour I am referring to everytime.
I would like to be able to write :

```
        var q =new BehaviourQueue(new BehaviourFactory()); // Queue here is of IBehaviour
        q
             .AddBehaviour<IBehaviourA>()
             .Configure(x => x.A = "someValueA")
             .WhenComplete(x => DoStuffWithSomeProperty(x.A));
        q
             .AddBehaviour<IBehaviourB>()
             .Configure(x => x.B = "someValueB")
             .WhenComplete(x => DoStuffWithSomeProperty(x.B));
```

Do you have any idea what I should write to be able to create a base typed list and add specific items and configuring it fluently ?

**Edit1:** Removed some code to avoid confusion. My ultimate goal is to write the above code.

Many thanks

Comment: just in case you don't get a satisfactory answer, you may want to consider posting this on [the StackExchange Code Review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

Change this and take it from there

```
public interface IBehaviourQueue<T> where T : IBehaviour
{
    void Run();
    BehaviourQueueItem<T> AddBehaviour<T>() where T
}
```

Make your class type specific, constrain the type and then just remove the type from your methods.

```
public class BehaviourQueue<T> : Queue<BehaviourQueueItem<T>>,  IBehaviourQueue<T> where T : IBehaviour
{
    private IBehaviourFactory factory;

    public BehaviourQueue(IBehaviourFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public BehaviourQueueItem<T> AddBehaviour()
    {
        T behaviour = factory.GetNew<T>();
        var queueItem = new BehaviourQueueItem<T>(behaviour);
        Enqueue(queueItem); 
        return queueItem;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        //Run each queue item
    }

}
```

Edit1: based on comments

```
public BehaviourQueueItem<T> ConfigureFor(Action<IBehaviour> dow)
{
    dow(behaviour);
    return this;
}
```

Edit2: more based on comments

```
public class BehaviourQueueItem<T>
{
    public T behaviour;
    public BehaviourQueueItem(T behaviour)
    {
        this.behaviour = behaviour;
    }
    public void WhenComplete(Func<T, bool> action)
    {
        CompletedAction = action;
    }

    public BehaviourQueueItem<T> ConfigureFor(Action<T> dow)
    {
        dow(behaviour);
        return this;
    }

    public Func<T, bool> CompletedAction { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I need to be able to choose which behaviour I want to add but your solution doesn't let me because you removed the type from AddBehaviour<T>. Your code doesn't allow me to write queue.AddBehaviour<IBehaviourB>(). The queue shouldn't be type specific as I can add as many different type of behaviour as I want.

Comment: Are all those behaviours implementing IBehaviour? If so, I don't see the problem with the code, just replace T with IBehaviour.

Comment: Your code will require that I fully type the queue to IBehaviourB or IBehaviourA. The queue needs to be IBehaviour only so I can add IBehaviourA or IBehaviourB and not having to specify the type in ConfigureFor and WhenComplete methods.

Comment: See my Edit1 for possible solution

Comment: Another thing is your implementation of BehaviourQueue doesn't match your interface IBehaviourQueue. Do you specify of not T on AddBehaviour. Ultimately you'll have to, otherwise you can't decide which type you want to inject. So I am not sure on what code your Edit solution it is based on.

Comment: You have some inconsistencies in your code. Many times you use `T` where you could just use `IBehaviour`. Also, when you constrain `T` with `where T : IBehaviour` you could just use `IBehavior` instead.
Edit2 added.

Comment: I agree with you. I started with a list of IBehaviour that I wanted to extend a bit and this is where I am at now. My ultimate goal is to be able to write the fluent code from my initial post.

Comment: Well, it looks to me you are only working with IBehaviour, so do your implementations with that in mind. Always reduce code assuming it will be that interface. From there, you can extend to make it generic in those places you need to.